# Bin packing with remotion

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I have a rectangle, and need to dynamically put and remove smaller rectangles in/from it. This is basically the bin packing problem, but also allows for item removal.

I cannot recreate everything after every removal because of its cost (it would make the complexity exponential): I need to add and remove rectangles dynamically. Also it's not simple (thus I'd avoid it) to move the rectangles already placed, and in particular it's not an option to move all the rectangles placed after a given one.

I'd need a C++ implementation, but in case it's not available, just an algorithm would be fine.

Comment: Are there constraints on removal? If not why not use a regular bin-packing algorithm and re-pack after every removal?

Comment: You're right, I didn't specify it. I have some efficiency constraints, would prefer to avoid recreating too often the whole thing. Also "moving" a rectangle is not possible.
I'll add this information to the answer.

Comment: Could you give a specific example of input with correct output so I can be sure about what it is that you're asking for?